# page automatically refreshes after scanning barcode which should not

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I am working on this project and I use a barcode scanner that has Windows CE 5.0 as its operating system. whenever I scan the barcode, the page automatically refreshes which should not. After it scans the barcode the user should be able to enter a number for quantity and after that the user will click the preview button which will take the user to another page. I've searched the net for solutions for this problem but still does not work. Help Please. Thank you.

```
<?php
    include("webconfig.php");
    ob_start();
    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION["USER_CODE"]) || $_SESSION["ACTIVE"] == '0')
        header("location:login.php");

    $barcode = $_REQUEST["barcode"];
    $item_desc = $_REQUEST["item_desc"];
    $price = $_REQUEST["price"];
    $quantity = $_REQUEST["txtQty"];

    $pricef = number_format($price, 2); 

    $sql = ibase_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM ITEM_MASTER WHERE ITEM_CODE = '$barcode'") or die(ibase_errmsg());
    $row = ibase_fetch_assoc($sql);
    $imgname = $row['IMGNAME']; 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="docs/css/metro.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="docs/css/metro-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="docs/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="docs/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="docs/js/metro.js"></script>
    <script src="docs/js/docs.js"></script>
    <script src="docs/js/prettify/run_prettify.js"></script>
    <script src="docs/js/ga.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ajaxcomplete.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="keyboard.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="keyboard.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="_img/assigns-favicon.PNG">

    <title>Albert Smith Signs - Warehouse Inventory System</title>  
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page-content">
        <div class="align-center">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Default -->
                <div class="panel">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="grid">
                            <div class="row cells12">
                                <!-- Default -->
                                <div class="panel">
                                    <div class="heading">
                                        <span class="title">ENTER QUANTITY</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <div class="grid">
                                            <div class="row cells12">
                                                <div class="cell colspan12">

                                                    <form onsubmit="return false;" method="post">
                                                        <label>Enter Quantity</label>
                                                        <br />
                                                        <div class="input-control text full-size" placeholder="Type search keyword here" data-role="input">
                                                            <!-- <input name="txtQty" class="keyboardInput" style="width: 225px;" type="text" value="1" autocomplete="off" /> -->
                                                            Scan Barcode
                                                            <input name="txtBarcode" id="ip" type="text" autofocus />
                                                            <br />
                                                            <br />
                                                            Enter Quantity
                                                            <input name="txtQty" id="next" type="text" />
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="cell colspan12">
                                                        <hr>
                                                        <br />
                                                        <br />
                                                        <br />
                                                        <br />
                                                        <br />

                                                        <input type="submit" onsubmit="return true;" name="btnPreview" style="width:80px; height:50px;" class="button primary rounded large-button" value="Preview" />
                                                        </div>

                                                </div>

                                                <?php
                                                    if(isset($_POST['btnPreview']) && $_POST['txtQty'] > 0)
                                                    {
                                                        $quantity = $_POST['txtQty'];
                                                        $barcode = $_POST['txtBarcode'];

                                                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ITEM_MASTER WHERE ITEM_CODE = '$barcode'";
                                                        $query = ibase_query($conn, $sql) or die(ibase_errmsg());

                                                        if ($row = ibase_fetch_assoc($query))
                                                        {
                                                            $item_desc = $row['ITEM_DESC'];
                                                            $price = $row['COST'];
                                                            header("location:preview.php?barcode=$barcode&quantity=$quantity&item_desc=$item_desc&price=$price");
                                                        }
                                                        else{
                                                            echo "Barcode not found";
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                ?>
                                                </form>
                                                <div class="cell colspan1">
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- panel -->
                            </div><!-- row cells12 -->
                        </div><!-- grid -->
                    </div><!-- content -->
                </div><!-- panel -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        //$("#ip").focus();
        /*var d = false;

        $("#ip").on('change', function(){
        //$("#ip").keyup(function(){
            if(d == false){
                $(".block").animate({"top": "-=50px"});
                d = true;
            }

            var v = $(this).val();
            $(".res").html("Search results for " + v );

            $("#next").focus();
        });*/

        $("#ip").focus();

        function init() {
            key_count_global = 0; // Global variable
            document.getElementById("ip").onkeypress = function() {
                key_count_global++;
                setTimeout("lookup("+key_count_global+")", 1000);//Function will be called 1 second after user types anything. Feel free to change this value.
            }
        }
        window.onload = init; //or $(document).ready(init); - for jQuery

        function lookup(key_count) {
            if(key_count == key_count_global) { // The control will reach this point 1 second after user stops typing.
                // Do the ajax lookup here.
                $("#next").focus();
            }
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Probably scanner issue, usually scanners do an action after they scan, I guessi n this case they are scan and enter... Making enter result in submitting your form, read the manual of the scanner.. This will most likely be your problem..

Comment: Thanks for that @Naruto. I'll check on that.

Answer (score 0):

It is supposed to do that. But you can stop it this way:

```
<form method="post" name="form" id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
```

Add this to your FORM like you see above.

```
onsubmit="return false;"
```

That will stop it from refreshing the page.